# Ignite loading similar data to particular instance

Tags: ignite, collocation

So i'm really new to apache ignite here. What i'm trying to do is load data having similar properties to a single rather than it being loaded to random instances. For example, say that some data of this form:

```
ROLL_NO
34569
12349
34439
45329
32359
43549
53259
34229
```

As u can see, the above data is all ending with 9. Say that i have two ignite instances A and B currently running. **Is there any way i can load these data ending with 9 to either of the instance A or B and NOT BOTH.**

Please let me know if this is possible and if so how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Ignite is a key-value storage, so you need to define what is a key and what is a value. The key should contain some ID that will uniquely identify an entry, and an affinity key that can be the same for multiple entries. All entries with the same affinity key will reside in same partition. Please refer to this page for more details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an AffinityKeyMapper for your cache. Read javadoc for details:

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/AffinityKeyMapper.java

Comment: can u please take some time to elaborate upon this, i'm not able to understand what is being done here. I'm really new to this.